# Returning Both Hours and Minutes for User Input

Tags: javascript, html, input, time, return

How would I return the hours and minutes for a JavaScript time input?

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="time" id="alarm" name="alarm"
   min="00:00" max="24:00" required>
```

And then here is the javascript

```
checkSaveAlarm.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alarmMinutes = alarmBox.value.getMinutes();
  alarmHours = alarmBox.value.getHours();
  alarmFunction(alarmHours, alarmMinutes); });
```

Doing the above returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const alarmFunction = console.log
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("change", ({ target: { value } }) => {
  const [alarmHours, alarmMinutes] = value.split(':');
  alarmFunction(alarmHours, alarmMinutes);
});
```

```html
<input type="time" id="alarm" name="alarm" min="00:00" max="24:00" required>
```